# How to connect webrtc from browser to node server as other peer and stream audio

Tags: webrtc

I want to get webrtc audio call from the browser connected  to the node server.
In effect I want to the node server itself to be the other peer.

Currently got webrtc calls locally working on the browser calling it self. 
Now instead need to make it call to node server.

What do you advise to get the node server connecting to the call and exchange audio streams.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is peer to peer. It requires server only for signalling. You have misunderstood things!